# How can I install Adobe Flash Player on 64-bit Ubuntu 16.10 Yakkety Yak

Tags: flash, adobe, 16.10

I go to https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/ and click on the "APT for Ubuntu 13.10+" but i get a message saying

"Unknown channel 'yakkety partner'"
The channel 'yakkety partner' is not known

Comment: Run `sudo apt install adobe-flashplugin`

Comment: Don't install directly from Adobe. Install the `adobe-flashplugin` package from Canonical Partner instead. https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-install-flash.html

Comment: Unfortunately the adobe-flashplugin is out of date.  Firefox wants to block it.

Comment: Why is this marked as an "exact duplicate" when A) It isn't and B) the solution offered at the linked articles don't work for yakkety?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer`